# Heroku / command : "git push heroku master" ERROR

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I'm trying to run my Java app on Heroku, but the git push command is failing:

[image]

How do I fix that?

Once sent, I can't open the application in the browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lram2.jpg)
and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxIOl.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ["Supported Java versions"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions):

> Heroku currently uses OpenJDK 8 to run your application by default. OpenJDK versions 13, 12, 11, and 7 are also available.

it seems like your code is intended to use Java 11, but Heroku uses the default Java 8.

Just follow [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version) and specify the version explicitly:

> You can specify a Java version by adding a file called `system.properties` to your application:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```